# table banner_vast_element_seq in OpenX project

Tags: php, openx

In our OpenX project we have **banner_vast_element_seq** table.
But OpenX doen't have code that works with this table.
Also OpenX doesn't have code that create this table.

Does anybody know how this table was created and how OpenX use it ?

Answer (score 0):

OpenX Source Ad Server's IAB VAST Plugin enables you to set up, deliver and track video ads in accordance with the IAB Digital Video Ad Serving Template (VAST) standard.
`banner_vast_element_seq` table related with Video ads.